# How to call an invoke repeating when a bool is true and canceling when it isn't?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to make my player launch an object every 3 seconds when a bool is true but I can't `InvokeRepeating` in `Update`, `Awake`, or `Start` without losing control of the function. How can I do this?

Comment: What do mean by "losing control of the function"?

Comment: Maybe what you need is [CancelInvoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.CancelInvoke.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
bool _shouldDoThing;
Coroutine _periodicAction;

IEnumerator DoThingPeriodically() {
    var delay = new WaitForSeconds(3f);

    while(true) {
        if (_shouldDoThing) {
            DoTheThing();
            yield return delay();
        } else {
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}


void Start() {
    _periodicAction = StartCoroutine(DoThingPeriodically());
}
```

This will call `DoTheThing()` once every three seconds (approximately) while the boolean is true. When the boolean is false, it will fall back to waiting until it is true again, then calling `DoTheThing()` immediately when it goes back to true if it's been at least three seconds.

If you ever want to stop the action, you can call `StopCoroutine(_periodicAction)` to abort it.

Comment: Does this check _shouldDoThing every frame if it's false?

Comment: It does, as you can verify by running the code.